# is lagrange error bound always true?

Tags: numerical-methods

I am asking this question because I am currently working with the function $f$ defined by $f(x) = 1/(1+x^2)$ and interpolating it at $n+1$ for the interval $[-2,2]$. I have found that it theoretically is less.

My finding are as follow:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline \
\text{Value of $n$} & \text{Maximum error (approximation)} & \text{Maximum error (Theoretical)} \\
\hline
2 & 0.305573 & 0.299488 \\
\hline
4 &  0.1618 & 0.0950007 \\
\hline
8 & 0.0992211 & 0.0167722 \\
\hline
18& 0.0717574 & 0.000890209 \\
\hline
\end{array}

Could there be cases where Lagrange bound is not satisfied?

Comment: You do not say you are approximating with Taylor polynomials and do not explicitly say the center of your expansion, but you should.  Also, the tag "lagrange-multiplier" does not apply to your question.  Finally, since I find the maximum of the true error for $n = 2$ is $16/5$ (occurring at $x = 2$) and the maximum of the Lagrange error is a little less than $50$ for $n = 2$ (occurring at $x = 2$), perhaps you should show your work for the true error and the error bound for at least one value of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to mention the exact location of the interpolation nodes. The interpolation error using nodes $x_0, \cdots, x_n \in [-2,2]$ is given by
$$
e_n(x) = \dfrac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}\prod_{i=0}^n(x-x_i),
$$

So the error can be bounded by

$$
\frac{\|f^{(n+1)}\|_{\infty} \| \prod_{i=0}^n(x-x_i)\|_{\infty}}{(n+1)!}.
$$

Depending on the location of the nodes, the term $ \| \prod_{i=0}^n(x-x_i)\|_{\infty}$ can behave very differently (you should look into Runge's example and the use of Chebyshev nodes).